# IntelliSense problem in VS Code with JavaScript file when entering "process" keyword

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have an empty file named "ask.js".  When I type "*process*" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it autocompletes to `ProcessInstruction`:

[image]

However, what I want to enter is `process.stdout.write("Hello ");` How can I get it to do this?

I am running the latest version 1.29 on Windows 10, and do not have any JavaScript-specific extensions installed.

Comment: Why do you need to press enter? If you’ve already typed all of `process`, can you not just add the `.` yourself?

Comment: What happens when you type `.` after you type `process`? Normally that's when you'd be prompted for the members on `process`. Also, does VS Code know that `process` exists? E.g., you have it set up to know you're targeting Node.js?

Comment: @MTCoster T.J. Crowder As soon as I type `.` it autocompletes as I have described.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right, it is not set up for Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install typings for node

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```